# Como puedo saber que maquinas tieneen fecha/hora erronea con ansible?

Tags: linux, script, ssh

Bueno eso es mi pregunta, como puedo verificar via ansible una lista de hosts que tengo y cada ciertas fechas al año en mi pais se cambia la hora. ¿Como puedo verificar que todas mis maquinas tengan la hora correcta? y si no la tienen se puede hacer que arroje un echo "Fecha incorrecta" o algo similar?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar ansible para realizar esto, ansible tiene una funcionalidad llamada gatherfacts la cual puede recuperar diversa informacion de los hosts a los que conecta:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible date timestamp example
    debug:
      var=ansible_date_time.time
```

Con este task de ansible obtendrias una respuesta similar a la siguiente:

```
ok: [servidorfqdn] => {
"ansible_date_time.date": "22:09:00"
}
```

Te recomiendo que investigues el uso de ansible para implementar esta solucion.

Puedes encontrar informacion mas extensa respecto a esta solucion aqui:
http://www.mydailytutorials.com/working-date-timestamp-ansible/